# "Live now, pay later"-what it implies?

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation, sayings

What's the meaning of "live now, pay later"?

I found a sentence on Cambridge dictionary:-

**Live now, pay later**- that's my philosophy of life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a variation (perhaps a parody) of "Buy now. Pay later".

This latter expression is common in advertising.  It means you can obtain the goods on "credit". If a car is "buy now, pay later" you can drive the car away now, with the promise that you will pay for the car later (on some agreed date)

The variation suggests "live now" (ie live life in a full way, enjoying many pleasures: food, drink, parties etc) and pay later (perhaps, this means pay the consequences of over-eating, drinking to excess and having fun)

Comment: Great!

Answer (score 2):

What is it you don't understand?

It is imperative in form (*live* and *pay* are verbs).

*Pay* is not necessarily to be taken literally, as "pay money", but a more general "pay the price, in whatever form that might take".

Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Which type of price it talks about?? I think it's talking about any type of price??

Comment: It doesn't specify. Whatever the cost might be to you - or to others - of the way you choose to live.

Comment: 'Drink a bottle of scotch & smoke two packs of cigarettes  a day - pay later" or "Buy up everything you can on your credit card - pay later." They're the same thing.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. - sleep with the woman next door while her 300 pound boxer husband is away